# Cannot call action method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Index(Int32, Int32, System.String, System.String, System.String, Int32 ByRef)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am doing asp.net MVC I want to show my index, but I got problem with calling the method.

Can somebody tell what am I doing wrong?

Here is my Index controller:

```
    public ActionResult Index(int pageNumber, int pageSize, string filter, string sortColumn, string sortOrder, out int totalCount)
    {
       List<UserActivityModels> userActivity = null;

        totalCount = 0;

        string sqlWhere = string.Empty;

        sqlWhere = string.IsNullOrEmpty(filter) ? sqlWhere :
            sqlWhere + "AND (ContactId LIKE @filter)";

        string sqlOrderBy = "ORDER BY" + sortColumn + "" + sortOrder;

        String sqlSelect = @"
           SELECT Id
            ,CreatedBy
            ,CreatedOn
            ,ModifiedBy
            ,ModifiedOn
            ,ContactId
            ,EntityName
            ,EntityId
            ,ActivityType
            ,ActivityStatus
            ,DueDate
            ,ActualEndDate
            ,MasqueradeOn
            ,MasqueradeBy 
        FROM UserActivity 
        #WHERE
        #ORDERBY
        LIMIT @PageSize OFFSET @PageNumber
        ";

        string sqlCount = @"
        SELECT COUNT(Id) TotalCount 
        FROM UserActivity
        #WHERE
              ";
        sqlCount = sqlCount.Replace("#WHERE", sqlWhere);
        sqlSelect = sqlSelect.Replace("#WHERE", sqlWhere);
        sqlSelect = sqlSelect.Replace("#ORDERBY", sqlOrderBy);

        try
        {
            using (IDbConnection db = new MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CRMPORTALSQLCONN"].ConnectionString))
            {
                userActivity = (List<UserActivityModels>)db.Query<UserActivityModels>(sqlSelect, new
                {
                    @filter = "%" + filter + "%",
                    @PageSize = pageSize,
                    @PageNumber = (pageNumber - 1) * pageSize
                });

                totalCount = (int)db.ExecuteScalar<int>(sqlCount, new
                {
                    @filter = filter
                });
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("Unable to retrieve data from DB.", ex);
        }

        return View(userActivity);

               }

    //POST: /UserActivity/Index
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(FormCollection collection)
    {
        try
        {
            // TODO: Add insert logic here

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

the error said:

> Cannot call action method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Index(Int32, Int32, System.String, System.String, System.String, Int32 ByRef)' on controller 'iCarAsia.SellerPortal.App.CRMPortal.Controllers.UserActivityController' because the parameter 'Int32& totalCount' is passed by reference.
>
> Parameter name: methodInfo

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This parameter `out int totalCount` causes your error. You are sending data over the internet, you can't pass a parameter by reference. I'm surprised that even compiles. If you want to return your totalcount, use

```
public ActionResult Index(int pageNumber, int pageSize, string filter, string sortColumn, 
                          string sortOrder)
{
   int totalCount = ...
   return Json(totalCount);
}
```

This will serialize your data to Json and return it with a `JsonResult` which inherits from `ActionResult`.

Comment: So which part should I make any changes is I may ask? I mean in coding format. Cause it's getting me frustrated already

Comment: @Botski Make `totalCount` part of your viewmodel and pass it like that

Comment: do you mean should I put totalCount into my model like public int TotalCount { get; set; } or at HTTp post?

Comment: @Botski Yes, you can pass it like that instead with an `out` parameter. Either that or you'll have to make an extra ajax request